# Is it possible to combine strtok() and substr()?

Tags: php

I've recently started working with PHP and am trying to make a list from a .txt BUT removing all the unnecessary components. 
a line got this

```
item = 0    egg    came_from_chicken
```

I want to remove the `item =` and the `came_from_chicken` which leaves me with `0 egg`.
Now after some searching I've found `substr()` to remove the first 5 characters of each of my lines. Later I've also found that `strtok()` can remove the rest of the unwanted text after the second tab. Unfortunately I cannot combine these. So my question is: How to remove the first 5 chars from each line and remove everything after the second tab from each line?

I've got this so far:

```
<?php
$lines = file('../doc/itemlist.txt');
$newf = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $newf[] = strtok($line, "\t") . "\t" . strtok("\t");
}
var_dump($newf);
?>
```

This works like a charm to remove everything after `egg` but still have to remove `item =`.

Comment: Because "item =" is not separated by a tab. Can you show an abstract format of a string in the file?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by an abstract format but I hope this is what you were looking for: https://gyazo.com/da5b84be7bdc5b4bc6e7fd32a3815ce6 Sorry am a real scrub still :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty way is to just wrap it all:

```
$newf[] = substr(strtok($line, "\t") . "\t" . strtok("\t"), 5);
```

<s>But, I personally have a dislike for `strtok()` (can't explain why, I just don't like it). If you don't need to strip everything off from the **second** tab, but from the **last** tab (in your example the second tab is the last tab), I would use `strrpos()` to find the location of the last tab, and dump that into `substr()`:</s>

```
$newf[] = substr($line, 5, strrpos($line, "\t")-5);
```

That `-5` is to compensate for the 5 characters you strip off from the beginning. If you need to start at character 6 instead of 5, you should also subtract 6 from whatever `strrpos()` returns.

**Edit** Never mind that whole last part, I just saw the example format you posted and you really need the second tab instead of the last tab.

Comment: True your quick-and-dirty way worked very well! my example has indeed just 2 tabs but the real format contains more. Thanks for the answer though, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work with *any* string preceeding the `=` symbol.

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $newf[] = implode("\t", array_slice(explode("\t", trim(explode('=', $line, 2)[1])), 0, 2));
}
```

Comment: Oh that worked! Thanks man. Totally didn't stop to think about implode and explode...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
<?php
$lines = file('./file.txt');
$newf = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $newf[] = preg_replace('/.*=\s*(.*)\t.*/s', '$1', $line);
}

var_dump($newf);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "0  egg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will be receiving similar patterns to the example you gave.

You can just do a simple line of:

```
$str = "item = 0    egg    came_from_chicken"; 
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
echo $parts[2] . $parts[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for using strtok but I believe it would be much easier to do the following code below:

```
<?php
    $lines  = '../doc/itemlist.txt';

    // array to store all data
    $newf   = array();

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        // you can do an explode which will turn it into an array and you can then get any values you want
        // $newf [] = strtok ($line, "\t") . "\t" . strtok("\t"); // throw away

        // lets say we use [item = 0    egg    came_from_chicken] as our string
        // we split it into an array for every tab or spaces found
        $values     = preg_split ('/\s+/', $line);
        //returns
        //  Array
        //  (
        //      [0] => item
        //      [1] => =
        //      [2] => 0
        //      [3] => egg
        //      [4] => came_from_chicken
        //      [5] => 
        //  )

        // lastly store your values which would be sub 2 and sub 4
        $newf []    = $values [2] . ' ' . $values [3];
    }

    var_dump($newf);

    // return
    // array (size=3)
    // 0 => string '0 aaa' (length=5)
    // 1 => string '1 bbb' (length=5)
    // 2 => string '2 ccc' (length=5)
?>
```